# Do photonic creation (anihilation) operators $a^\dagger$ ($a$) taken at different times commute?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, operators, commutator, time-evolution

This question was spawned from a discussion with my supervisor on the nature of the second-order correlation function

\begin{align}
G^{(2)} (t_1,t_2) &= <\Psi| E^-(t_1) E^-(t_2)  E^+(t_2) E^+(t_1)|\Psi>, \tag{1}
\end{align}
with

\begin{align}
E^+(t) = (E^-(t))^\dagger \propto \int^\infty_{-\infty} d\omega \, a_\omega e^{-i\omega t}
\end{align}
being the positive (negative) frequency parts of the electric field operator 
\begin{align}
E(t) = E^+(t)+E^-(t).
\end{align}

The question now is, if (and when) the operators within $G^{(2)}$ commute. That is, do the Heisenberg picture representations of the photonic creation (anihilation) operators $a^\dagger_\omega(t) =  a_\omega^\dagger e^{+i\omega t}$ ($a_\omega(t) =  a_\omega e^{-i\omega t} $) in a single mode (labeled by its angular frequency $\omega$) commute at different times.

My take was that for all times $t$ we can see that the time dependence of $a$ is simply a c-number and we find 
\begin{align}
[a_\omega(t),a_\omega^\dagger(t+\Delta t)] = [a_\omega,a^\dagger_\omega] e^{i\omega\Delta t} = e^{i\omega\Delta t}.\tag{2}
\end{align}

However, he claimed that at different times we could consider the operators to refer to different temporal modes and that they thus commuted.

(I am somewhat unfamiliar with the concept of temporal modes,but understand that for well localized wave packets we can at some point neglect interaction between them which would be reflected by a commutation of their creation and anihilation operators. Still in my understanding the time dependence here is fundamentally different from modes in frequency, because it enters as a consequence of the photons being solutions to a real physical differential equation that has a certain time behaviour.)

He thus wanted to show that
\begin{align}
G^{(2)}\propto <\Psi| n(t_2)n(t_1)|\Psi>, \tag{3}
\end{align} and that it thus represents "the probability [density] to find a photon at time $t_1$ and a photon at time $t_2$" in the context of the two-photon state in question.

I am assuming this is correct in some cases and am looking for an understanding of what kind of light allows for this picture. We were talking about interference experiments with two-photon states from an SPDC source.

I also am unsure if I am missing the point by not regarding the finite time-resolution of a real detector.

Comment: What you wrote for the time dependence of annihilation operator only works for a *free* theory. If we could compute that in general we would solve the many body problem!

Comment: Yes. I simply thought that was the meaning of $G^{(2)}$ when talking about light sources. That we evaluate the $E^\pm$s in free space. Is not correct?

Comment: Yes if you are talking about the (free) electromagnetic field (with no charges around), that is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$a_ω$s for different ωs commute, but not for the same ω, which you exploited already, in a somewhat freaky bypass of plain Fourier transforming.

Your teacher almost certainly had you evaluate
$$
[E^+(t),E^-(\tau)]\propto \int\!\! d\omega d\omega' ~ [a_\omega, a_{\omega'}^\dagger ]~ e^{-i\omega t +i \omega' \tau}\\ 
\propto \int d\omega  ~    e^{-i\omega (t- \tau)} \propto \delta (t- \tau)~.
$$

Comment: I see. Then in applying this commutator to (1) I indeed find $G^{(2)} = <E^-(t_1)E^+(t_2)E^-(t_2) E^+(t_1)>-<E^-(t_2) E^+(t_1)>\delta(t_1-t_2)$, which is propportional to (3) for $t_1\neq t_2$.

My remaining questions would be if there is some limit behaviour as $t_1\rightarrow t_2$ and if there are any restrictions on using these commutators? I found mentioned in (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.42.4102) that narrow bandwidth approximations needed to extend the integration range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ can only be made for certain light.

Comment: Ugh.... There is an industry of multiplying the integrand of the last line with a Gaussian in $\omega$ of a given width... Then the integral is the FT of the Gaussian, also a Gaussian in $t-\tau$, except with *inverse* the frequency width, instead of the $\delta$ function...So the more restricted the frequency range, the broader the Gaussian in $t-\tau$.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood the setting. You are talking about granular $\omega$ instead of continuous one? Again, there is a cottage industry of converting continuous FTs to discrete ones.

Comment: The $\omega$ are indeed supposed to be continous.

Comment: However the light I am considering is a two-photon state of the form $|{\psi}> = \int^\infty_{-\infty}  \int^\infty_{-\infty} d\omega_s d\omega_i \left(\frac{T_e}{\pi}\right)\delta(\omega_p - (\omega_s + \omega_i)) sinc \left(\frac{T_e }{2}(\omega_s-\omega_i)\right) e^{i\omega_s \tau} a^\dagger_{\omega_s} a^\dagger_{\omega_i} | 0>$, where $T_e$ is the correlation or entanglement time and $\omega_p$ is the pump frequency of the light pumping the SPDC source. In this case also the spectral function would enter into the integrand and widen the "delta function" I suppose.

Comment: Probably... any relaxation of the constant being Fourier trasnformed  will yield a relaxed delta function, so some type of a finite height, finite width peak...